# Why don't I get the same value of percentage ionic character of a particular molecule from different equations?

Tags: bond, electronegativity, dipole, valence-bond-theory

About the ionic character of a polar covalent compound Pauling gave two equations as

- 1. [1-$e^{.25(x_a - x_b)}] $%
- 2. [18$(x_a-x_b)^{1.4}$]%

     Hanary and Smith gave the equation
- 3. [$16(x_a-x_b)+3.5(x_a-x_b)^2$]%

Where $x_a$ and $x_b$ stands for the electronegativity of $a$ and $b$ atom in bond $a-b$.

Now if I put $x_a-x_b = 2,$ The 1st, 2nd & 3rd equations respectively give the value as 
     *-.648%, 47.5% & 46%.* What is the reason behind these  different values of percentage ionic character of the same molecule? At where       am I wrong?

Comment: You are wrong in thinking that percentage of ionic character  is a real observable thing, like mass or energy. It isn't. (Neither is electronegativity, BTW.)

Comment: @IvanNeretin then how Pauling gave the equations and how do we have an electronegativity table?

Comment: When Pauling gave the equations, he knew their limitations. As for the electronegativity table, we surely have not one, but **many** such tables, all subtly different.